# Three letters at the end of the parasha

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, writing-printing, pentateuch-chumash, parsha-torah-portion

What are the three letters either samechs or pe's which are at the end of the parasha in the Chumash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the article on [parashah in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashah) .

Some extracts from it:

> A parashah formally means a section of a biblical book in the
>   masoretic text of the Tanakh (Hebrew Bible).[1] In the masoretic text,
>   parashah sections are designated by various types of spacing between
>   them, as found in Torah scrolls, scrolls of the books of Nevi'im or
>   Ketuvim (especially megillot), masoretic codices from the Middle Ages
>   and printed editions of the masoretic text.

You have used the word "parasha" which does not fit this definition. What I think you mean is "sedrah".

> In most modern Torah scrolls and Jewish editions of the Bible, there
>   are two types of parashot, an "open portion" (parashah petuhah) and a
>   "closed portion" (parashah setumah). An "open portion" is roughly
>   similar to a modern paragraph: The text of the previous portion ends
>   before the end of the column (leaving a space at the end of the line),
>   and the new "open" portion starts at the beginning of the next line
>   (but with no indentation). A "closed portion", on the other hand,
>   leaves a space in the middle of the line of text, where the previous
>   portion ends before the space, and the next portion starts after it,
>   towards the end of the line of text.
>
> In some manuscripts and in many printed editions, an "open portion"
>   (petuhah) is abbreviated with the Hebrew letter "פ" (peh), and a
>   "closed portion" (setumah) with the Hebrew letter "ס" (samekh), often
>   in place of the visual gap in the line.[8]
>
> The five books of the Torah have been broken down into their weekly
>   Torah readings for convenience. The weekly Torah readings always begin
>   at a parashah break, with the single exception of Vayechi (Genesis
>   47:28).

This parashah break is signified by three "פ"s at the end of the sedrah. Eg [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14362&st=&pgnum=99).

The end of the sedrah ויגש which is the sedrah before ויחי looks like [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14361&st=&pgnum=580).