# Why do most Chumashim mark the end of a Sidra with 3 parsha markings?

Tags: torah-reading, pentateuch-chumash, publications, parsha-torah-portion

With the exception of the end of *Vayigash*, every Sidrah (Shabbat weekly Torah reading) ends at a parsha (paragraph end.)

When there is a parsha end in the middle of the sidrah, Chumashim use a single ס or פ. At the end of the sidrah, most Chumashim use 3  ס or פ. (See an example [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=242).)

Why do they use more than one, and why specifically 3 (as opposed to 2 or 4, etc.)?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34775/three-letters-at-the-end-of-the-parasha

Comment: and if it was 2 or 4, you'd ask the same question.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות You're mechavein to the first three sources [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89607/13438).

Comment: @Alex you may remember who awarded a bounty on that question...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I remember it well.

Comment: @ רבותמחשבות "and if it was 2 or 4, you'd ask the same question". Actually, not, b/c I would be asking about 2 or 4, not 3 ;-) And, if you had an answer, you would give me the same answer regardless of the number I asked about, right? So what's your point?